# 2015 macbook air has frequent kernel panics (10.15.7)

Tags: catalina, kernel-panic

I have a 2015 macbook air running catilina (10.15.7) that has frequent kernel panics.

I have no idea how to fix this because everything I see about kernel panics for macbooks is about the sleep kernel panics on macbook airs. In my limited knowledge of the logs, it seems that maybe the virtualbox ktexts are the problem?

Has anyone else had anything like this? The panics have gotten much more frequent and I dont know how to stop it. It happens maybe 4-5x a day now. Please let me know if I can provide more information to you guys

Here are the kernel panic logs that i've saved

```
Mac OS version:
19H1030

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Apr 12 20:57:45 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.28.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BB1171FD-A9E3-3D24-92F7-F4DD45974EFD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000007600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8007800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8007700000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11247348971604
last loaded kext at 10985186640625: >!UAudio    323.4 (addr 0xffffff7f8b16f000, size 434176)
last unloaded kext at 11075719563652: >usb.!UHostCompositeDevice    1.2 (addr 0xffffff7f89ff9000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.12
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>AGPM   111.4.4
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.7
>!AHDA  283.15
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.4
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

and here are 3 kernel panic logs from today (one happened when I was writing this)

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff80049709a8): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.16: expected 0xc0ffee347fd07b2a but found 0xc0ff6e347fd07b2a, bits changed 0x800000000000, at offset 0 of 16 in element 0xffffff8019427e00, cookies 0x3f0011b46692050a 0x53521bc9f6eae6d"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.141.28.1/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:1233
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8105bf2ff0 : 0xffffff800491763d 
0xffffff8105bf3040 : 0xffffff8004a51b25 
0xffffff8105bf3080 : 0xffffff8004a436ae 
0xffffff8105bf30d0 : 0xffffff80048bda40 
0xffffff8105bf30f0 : 0xffffff8004916d07 
0xffffff8105bf31f0 : 0xffffff80049170f7 
0xffffff8105bf3240 : 0xffffff80050be82c 
0xffffff8105bf32b0 : 0xffffff80049709a8 
0xffffff8105bf32e0 : 0xffffff8004970b11 
0xffffff8105bf3310 : 0xffffff80049707dc 
0xffffff8105bf3340 : 0xffffff80049711e9 
0xffffff8105bf3360 : 0xffffff8004972858 
0xffffff8105bf33a0 : 0xffffff800496ebff 
0xffffff8105bf34d0 : 0xffffff8004924584 
0xffffff8105bf3540 : 0xffffff8004feea17 
0xffffff8105bf3570 : 0xffffff7f86f67f4b 
0xffffff8105bf38b0 : 0xffffff7f86f6580b 
0xffffff8105bf3990 : 0xffffff7f86f36b89 
0xffffff8105bf39f0 : 0xffffff7f87f5cfa5 
0xffffff8105bf3a30 : 0xffffff7f86f3ec2d 
0xffffff8105bf3a80 : 0xffffff7f86f40451 
0xffffff8105bf3ac0 : 0xffffff800505073e 
0xffffff8105bf3b10 : 0xffffff7f86f4064a 
0xffffff8105bf3b60 : 0xffffff8005059963 
0xffffff8105bf3ca0 : 0xffffff8004a00622 
0xffffff8105bf3db0 : 0xffffff800491d3a8 
0xffffff8105bf3e10 : 0xffffff80048f3d35 
0xffffff8105bf3e70 : 0xffffff800490ab02 
0xffffff8105bf3f00 : 0xffffff8004a290a5 
0xffffff8105bf3fa0 : 0xffffff80048be226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.7.4)[4F99A1E8-80CF-3FB8-81E6-003E6FB9287C]@0xffffff7f86f14000->0xffffff7f86fd7fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[C65FA4DC-ED21-3A31-A591-C451CF0F928F]@0xffffff7f85387000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B4389948-0918-363E-8E70-0FBC89B384CA]@0xffffff7f85502000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[3977100E-EC90-3633-8701-E2C4EA120DB7]@0xffffff7f86690000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[5FD30AFD-9512-3600-AD94-7048F96F8951]@0xffffff7f86e9a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[CAB42AFD-E93C-3FC9-850D-91DC66AF0D02]@0xffffff7f85430000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics(14.0.7)[FB9D8DD2-992C-3EA1-B92C-289A7EBCFC74]@0xffffff7f87f0a000->0xffffff7f87fa4fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B4389948-0918-363E-8E70-0FBC89B384CA]@0xffffff7f85502000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOSurface(269.11)[3977100E-EC90-3633-8701-E2C4EA120DB7]@0xffffff7f86690000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(576.1)[5FD30AFD-9512-3600-AD94-7048F96F8951]@0xffffff7f86e9a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.7.4)[4F99A1E8-80CF-3FB8-81E6-003E6FB9287C]@0xffffff7f86f14000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

Mac OS version:
19H1030

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Apr 12 20:57:45 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.28.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BB1171FD-A9E3-3D24-92F7-F4DD45974EFD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000004600000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004800000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004700000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 8967875990071
last loaded kext at 8853920341258: >!UAudio 323.4 (addr 0xffffff7f8816f000, size 434176)
last unloaded kext at 8915593172783: >usb.cdc   5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f87c27000, size 28672)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.12
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.7
>!AHDA  283.15
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.4
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f95459231): nvme: "Fatal error occurred. CSTS=0xffffffff US[1]=0x0 US[0]=0x24 VID=0xffff DID=0xffff
. FW Revision=HP03\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IONVMeFamily/IONVMeFamily-470.100.17/IONVMeController.cpp:5320
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff811eaf39e0 : 0xffffff801371763d 
0xffffff811eaf3a30 : 0xffffff8013851b25 
0xffffff811eaf3a70 : 0xffffff80138436ae 
0xffffff811eaf3ac0 : 0xffffff80136bda40 
0xffffff811eaf3ae0 : 0xffffff8013716d07 
0xffffff811eaf3be0 : 0xffffff80137170f7 
0xffffff811eaf3c30 : 0xffffff8013ebe82c 
0xffffff811eaf3ca0 : 0xffffff7f95459231 
0xffffff811eaf3cc0 : 0xffffff7f95444362 
0xffffff811eaf3e20 : 0xffffff8013e2f099 
0xffffff811eaf3e90 : 0xffffff8013e2efb9 
0xffffff811eaf3ec0 : 0xffffff8013759605 
0xffffff811eaf3f40 : 0xffffff8013759131 
0xffffff811eaf3fa0 : 0xffffff80136bd13e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily(2.1)[499343D7-E5A6-31A6-BE35-CB6755394EF7]@0xffffff7f95436000->0xffffff7f95478fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[C65FA4DC-ED21-3A31-A591-C451CF0F928F]@0xffffff7f94187000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B4389948-0918-363E-8E70-0FBC89B384CA]@0xffffff7f94302000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM(2.1)[A24A665E-8A96-3B20-BD02-F7AAA9B42F5F]@0xffffff7f9450a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[F3D120E5-29D0-32C7-A09A-E88B84675F9C]@0xffffff7f94065000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[CAB42AFD-E93C-3FC9-850D-91DC66AF0D02]@0xffffff7f94230000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19H1030

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Apr 12 20:57:45 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.28.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BB1171FD-A9E3-3D24-92F7-F4DD45974EFD
Kernel slide:     0x0000000013400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8013600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8013500000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 72849900041
last loaded kext at 33916064068: >!ABacklight   180.3 (addr 0xffffff7f96b08000, size 24576)
last unloaded kext at 61507416825: >!A!ILpssI2C 3.0.60 (addr 0xffffff7f94646000, size 40960)
loaded kexts:
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ASMCLMU   212
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

```
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7fa1a59231): nvme: "Fatal error occurred. CSTS=0xffffffff US[1]=0x0 US[0]=0x25 VID=0xffff DID=0xffff
. FW Revision=HP03\n"@/AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IONVMeFamily/IONVMeFamily-470.100.17/IONVMeController.cpp:5320
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8120c439e0 : 0xffffff801fd1763d 
0xffffff8120c43a30 : 0xffffff801fe51b25 
0xffffff8120c43a70 : 0xffffff801fe436ae 
0xffffff8120c43ac0 : 0xffffff801fcbda40 
0xffffff8120c43ae0 : 0xffffff801fd16d07 
0xffffff8120c43be0 : 0xffffff801fd170f7 
0xffffff8120c43c30 : 0xffffff80204be82c 
0xffffff8120c43ca0 : 0xffffff7fa1a59231 
0xffffff8120c43cc0 : 0xffffff7fa1a44362 
0xffffff8120c43e20 : 0xffffff802042f099 
0xffffff8120c43e90 : 0xffffff802042efb9 
0xffffff8120c43ec0 : 0xffffff801fd59605 
0xffffff8120c43f40 : 0xffffff801fd59131 
0xffffff8120c43fa0 : 0xffffff801fcbd13e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily(2.1)[499343D7-E5A6-31A6-BE35-CB6755394EF7]@0xffffff7fa1a36000->0xffffff7fa1a78fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity(1.0.5)[C65FA4DC-ED21-3A31-A591-C451CF0F928F]@0xffffff7fa0787000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[B4389948-0918-363E-8E70-0FBC89B384CA]@0xffffff7fa0902000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM(2.1)[A24A665E-8A96-3B20-BD02-F7AAA9B42F5F]@0xffffff7fa0b0a000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily(2.1)[F3D120E5-29D0-32C7-A09A-E88B84675F9C]@0xffffff7fa0665000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[CAB42AFD-E93C-3FC9-850D-91DC66AF0D02]@0xffffff7fa0830000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19H1030

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Mon Apr 12 20:57:45 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.28.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BB1171FD-A9E3-3D24-92F7-F4DD45974EFD
Kernel slide:     0x000000001fa00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801fc00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801fb00000
System model name: MacBookAir7,2 (Mac-937CB26E2E02BB01)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: YES (0x0)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 617061631323
last loaded kext at 39078214812: org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp 6.1.12 (addr 0xffffff7fa3569000, size 28672)
last unloaded kext at 491531744068: >usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0 (addr 0xffffff7fa0dfc000, size 24576)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.12
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.12
com.intel.kext.intelhaxm    7.5.1
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
>AudioAUUC  1.70
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>pmtelemetry    1
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IBDWGraphics    14.0.7
>!AHDA  283.15
>eficheck   1
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!ABacklight    180.3
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!ACameraInterface  7.6.0
>!A!IBDWGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.7
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!UCardReader   489.120.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.4
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
@kext.triggers  1.0
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>!AMultitouchDriver 3440.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3440.8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
>!AHSSPIHIDDriver   59
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
>!AHSSPISupport 59
>!A!ILpssSpi!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

--

`kextstat | grep -v com.apple` output is below

```
Index Refs Address            Size       Wired      Name (Version) UUID <Linked Against>
  164    0 0xffffff7f83cab000 0x29000    0x29000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm (7.5.1) D0CC7B8F-1F62-33B1-BE6B-B5573D2A607B <8 6 5 3 1>
  176    3 0xffffff7f83cd4000 0xf2000    0xf2000    org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv (6.1.22) 1D7585CE-080A-304D-8F83-466458C5B2A1 <8 6 5 3 1>
  177    0 0xffffff7f83dc6000 0x8000     0x8000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB (6.1.22) FFEC89DC-6242-369E-96FF-81063D9625B2 <176 170 60 8 6 5 3 1>
  178    0 0xffffff7f83dce000 0x5000     0x5000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt (6.1.22) B15B9D1B-A553-351A-AA00-3F1A1993BF7F <176 8 6 5 3 1>
  179    0 0xffffff7f83de0000 0x6000     0x6000     org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp (6.1.22) 66101E0E-D20E-3395-81B1-4554ECDA72C1 <176 6 5 1>
```

Comment: These Kernel Panic happen anytime or only when using VirtualBox?

Comment: @Jean_JD happens anytime, even with no applications open. It seems to happen more when chrome is open

Comment: Can you try boot in Safe Mode (hold Shift key at boot) and verify, if it's possible, work in this mode an verify if you got kernel Panic ? This could indicate  you have a "bad" non-apple kext .

Comment: @Jean_JD I worked a good amount in safe mode (~1.5hrs) and had no kernel panics. Usually I would have Atleast 1 in that time frame. Would it help if I showed you a list of all the non-apple kexts? I thought I saw a bash command that did that

Comment: You can try this command : ``kextstat | grep -v com.apple``.  May be in "normal mode".

Comment: @Jean_JD Heres the output when I run that command, I posted it as an answer bc it was too many characters for a comment

Comment: You can't add it at your thirst post? Else this list is from the Safe or Normal Mode? What is the use of this : https://github.com/intel/haxm  -> com.intel.kext.intelhaxm ?

Comment: The kext list is from normal mode. I believe that the haxm kext is used by android studio for the emulator

Comment: Ok. You can try suppress temporary this kext (intel and VirtualBox if it's possible for you). You can too download Etrecheck et scan your system. It's a very good utility. ;-)